# JavaScript Returning Previous Value Immediately after Changing the Value

Tags: javascript

I have a single html document that simulates many pages by modifying the content and url as users click through the page.

In my JavaScript there is a place I use `history.back()`. This works as expected changing the url and content (even though the user really stays on the same html document). However, immediately after I use `history.back()` I try to get the users new `window.location`. This is still showing the previous url instead of the new one.

Do I need to force some type of update, refresh, calculation, garbage collection or something in-between those two lines of code so I get the new url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try waiting for the next tick before checking the new `window.location`:

```js
history.back()
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(window.location)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Listen for the [`popstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event) event. Browsers handle timing `history.back()` slightly different from each other.

```
window.onpopstate = logHistory;

function logHistory(e) {
  console.log(this.location);
}
```